# Multiple level wildcards and SSL

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm trying to have this working:

dev.somedomain.tld
*.dev.somedomain.tld
*.somedomain.tld

I created two SSL certs, one which contains dev.somedomain.tld and *.somedomain.tld, and the other contains *.dev.somedomain.tld.

I also created two VHost:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.5.47:443>
  ServerName dev.somedomain.tld
  ServerAlias *.somedomain.tld 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.5.47:443>
  ServerName something.dev.somedomain.tld
  ServerAlias *.dev.somedomain.tld 
</VirtualHost>
```

Problem is: anything.dev.somedomain.tld goes to the dev.somedomain.tld vhost, no matter the priority in Apache.

Is there something special to do for higher level wildcards?

Comment: Have you tried to put VirtualHosts in another order? May be it works in Apache. :)

Comment: Yes, I did try to reverse the order. That's why I said "no matter the priority in Apache".

Answer (score 0):

According Apache documentation VirtualHosts order matter. You could check VirtualHosts order by running `httpd -S`.

See my example with different VirtualHosts order:

```
[root@~]# httpd -S
VirtualHost configuration:
192.168.5.47:443       is a NameVirtualHost
     default server dev.somedomain.tld (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:353)
     port 443 namevhost dev.somedomain.tld (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:353)
             wild alias *.somedomain.tld
     port 443 namevhost something.dev.somedomain.tld (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:358)
             wild alias *.dev.somedomain.tld

[root@~]# httpd -S
VirtualHost configuration:
192.168.5.47:443       is a NameVirtualHost
     default server something.dev.somedomain.tld (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:353)
     port 443 namevhost something.dev.somedomain.tld (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:353)
             wild alias *.dev.somedomain.tld
     port 443 namevhost dev.somedomain.tld (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:358)
             wild alias *.somedomain.tld
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so something.dev.somedomain.tld was in a file called "5-something.dev.somedomain.tld.conf" while "dev.somedomain.tld" was in "20-dev.somedomain.tld.conf". I was expecting something.dev.somedomain.tld to load before, but no, it loads after. I had to set the priority to "05" instead of "5", problem is gone.

Comment: That problem caused by sort. Alphabetical sort it as 20,5. After your fix sort looks like 05, 20. So order is matter. :)